# Windows Shortcut for bash command: what does {12345678 ...} ~ mean?

Tags: shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the Windows Subsystem for Linux and this shortcut for Ubuntu Bash Desktop:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe {12345678 ...} ~
```

What does {12345678 ...} ~ mean after bash.exe ?

Comment: That's in the windows shortcut itself? So it could be a windows shortcut feature?

Comment: Provide full command. which distro did you install? How did you install? Windows 10 full version? Are you familiar with GUID and C language and `/bin/bash` options?

Comment: Any reply......